# Blocked shot on a foul by another player

Tags: basketball, nba

In the NBA, if PlayerA fouls ShooterA on a shot attempt and PlayerB cleanly blocks the shot (no foul called on PlayerB), does the block count in the stat sheet?

If the answer is no, is there a stat that tracks this?

Comment: If a player is fouled while shooting and he misses (blocked) the shot never happened in the world of stats, if he makes it it counts as a field goal attempt and make.   Therefore a block cannot happen even with the most advanced stats.   There is no way you would give someone credit for blocking a guy that was fouled - not only useless, but unfair, and arbitrary in that some of these blocks could be very very easy - imagine guy getting hammered and throwing up "whatever" from his hip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Wikipedia about blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(basketball))

> ...Also, on a shooting foul, a blocked shot cannot be awarded or
>   counted, even if the player who deflected the field goal attempt is
>   different from the player who committed the foul...

If a block is made after a shooting foul is called, it is not credited, nor is it tracked.

Answer (score -1):

Only if it is a shooting foul.  If Player B blocks the shot, he is awarded a block.

Some fouls are called in the progress of a play, but are determined to be on the floor (non-shooting foul).  In this instance, neither a shot attempt, nor a block is counted.  No stats are kept for this block.